# Login to Elgg through URL?

Tags: php, android, webview, elgg

I am trying to login to My Elgg client through the URL, Like http://page.com/&username=Jennifer&password=pass123. Is it possible to implement something like this or is their any other way? I'm trying to have a user enter his username and password on my app and have it sign them in. Is their anyway to accomplish this?

Comment: You can use webservices for this purpose. But what after login? I mean you want to redirect user in elgg or just use it's data.

Answer (score 0):

Action tokens control won't allow you to fabricate login URL without getting action tokens first.

Usually when writing an app, you should be interested in using [web services](http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Web_Services). They have a similar method (services/api/rest/json?method=auth.gettoken) that returns auth token, but as I understand, you want to establish session in the browser. This way, I'd write similar method to auth.gettoken, that would perform login(), and than make sure that cookies get passed to the target browser.

There are more alternatives, but as I understand, you decided that login form is implemented directly on the app.